# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string ""

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am having a hard time playing with the cosine function. The remaining code is working fine as far as the integer data type functions are concerned but I can't understand why compiler is giving the error with the double data type functions.

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/


import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
*
* @author amjad
*/

public class CalculatorVisual extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

//Methods will be used from this class
CalculatorProps cp = new CalculatorProps();

JTextField val1, val2;
JButton btnPlus, btnMinus, btnMultiply, btnDiv, btnSine, btnCosine, btnTan, 
        btnPow, btnSqrt, btnModulo, btnLog;

public CalculatorVisual(){

    super("Calculator - Visual");

    Container c = getContentPane();
    val1 = new JTextField(20);
    val2 = new JTextField(20);

    btnPlus = new JButton("+");
    btnMinus = new JButton("-");
    btnMultiply = new JButton("X");
    btnDiv = new JButton("/");
    btnCosine = new JButton("Cos");

    btnPlus.addActionListener(this);
    btnMinus.addActionListener(this);
    btnMultiply.addActionListener(this);
    btnDiv.addActionListener(this);
    btnCosine.addActionListener(this);

    JPanel p = new JPanel();

    p.add(val1); 
    p.add(val2);
    p.add(btnPlus);
    p.add(btnMinus);
    p.add(btnMultiply);
    p.add(btnDiv);
    p.add(btnCosine);

    c.add(p);


}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   int a = Integer.parseInt(val1.getText());
   int b = Integer.parseInt(val2.getText());

   if(e.getSource()== btnPlus){
       val1.setText("" + cp.sum(a, b));
       val2.setText("");
   }

   else if(e.getSource()== btnMinus){
       val1.setText("" + cp.sub(a, b));
       val2.setText("");
   }

   else if(e.getSource() == btnMultiply){
       val1.setText("" + cp.multiply(a, b));
       val2.setText("");
   }

   else if(e.getSource() == btnDiv){
       val1.setText("" + cp.divide(a, b));
       val2.setText("");
   }

   else if(e.getSource() == btnCosine){
       double txtDouble = (double)a;
       double d_result = cp.calcCos(txtDouble);
       val1.setText(Double.toString(d_result));
       val2.setText("");
   }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   CalculatorVisual calc = new CalculatorVisual();
   calc.setSize(300,300);
   calc.setVisible(true);
   calc.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
}
}
```

Here is the stack trace

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at CalculatorVisual.actionPerformed(CalculatorVisual.java:68)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at CalculatorVisual.actionPerformed(CalculatorVisual.java:68)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Here is the functions' class which I am using in CalculatorVisual class.

```
public class CalculatorProps {

int val1,val2, int_result;
double d_val1, d_val2, d_result;

CalculatorProps(){

}

public int sum(int val1,int val2)
{
    return int_result = val1+val2;
}

public int sub(int val1,int val2){
    return int_result = val1-val2;
}

public int multiply(int val1,int val2){
    return int_result = val1*val2;
}

public int divide(int val1,int val2){
    return int_result = val1 / val2;
}

public int remainder(int val1,int val2){
        return int_result = val1 % val2;
}

double sqrt(double d_val1){
    double d_result=Math.sqrt(d_val1);
    return d_result;
}

double pow(double d_val1,double d_val2){
    double d_result=Math.pow(d_val1,d_val2);
    return d_result;
}

int fact(int val1){
    if(val1<=1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (val1*fact(val1-1));
}

public double calcSine(double d_val1){
    double d_result= Math.sin(d_val1);
    return d_result;
}

public double calcCos(double d_val1){
    double d_result = Math.cos(d_val1);
    return d_result;
}

public double calcTan(double d_val1){
    double radians = Math.toRadians(d_val1);
    return d_result = Math.tan(radians);
}

public double calcLog(double d_val1){
    double d_result = Math.log(d_val1);
    return d_result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, what must be happening is that `val1` or `val2` has no text when you click the button.  That's exactly what the error message is complaining about.  You should check for that case and handle it at the top of your `actionPerformed` method.

Comment: As soon as I commented the val1 and val2 at the beginning of actionPerformed method it gave me the desired result. Thanks a lot for your answer! So suggest me what would be the better way to getText at the start or in the buttons if/else blocks in actionPerformed?